# Create a view basing on current time (MySql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a lot of records of Events. For each row I have two columns “start date” and “end date” . In order to improve performance I was wondering to develop a chron job that create a mini table with only the Events for next 20 hours. But would be even better to have a view that basing on the current time filters only the specific rows. Is that possible in MySql?

**Edit:** is the view alway worst, in terms of performances, compared to a new small table correct?

Comment: Depends on how many accesses there will be.  Creating a small table requires accessing the relevant records once, but creating a new table is a rather heavy-duty operation, certainly requiring at least ten times more time and several non-related-to-a-view operations.  A view can be optimized to have less impact than a table create.  But what is the relative number of reads of the data and can they be buffered outside the d/b system?

Comment: It’s behind a webservice, that should reply to a hundreds of request per second , that’s why I need to improve performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can create a view that references `NOW()` or `CURDATE()` in the where clause. e.g.

```
create view your_special_v as
    select col1, col2, col3
    from your table
    where datetimecolumn >= now()
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the reply, very good! Now I just need to understand how to sum 20 hours to “now”!

Comment: Is that going to improve the performance or a chron job and a new small table is always better?

Comment: If your table has appropriate indexes then a filtered view can perform well. But a small table is always going to be very fast. However you have the task of maintaining this small table. At some point each day? hour? it will become "out of date" and need to be refreshed. Not insurmountable of course.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Views do not store data. Its just a representation of table for required data. Like we retrieve selected columns from table by mentioning the names of columns instead of firing "select * from tablename;" query which retrieve us all the columns. 
Talking about your question first of all if you want to perform cron job you need to store data. that is not possible with views. So your answer is no we can not perform cron job on views. But you can create events for particular condition on your table...

Regards,
Iroti Mahajan
imahajan@shilpasys.com

Comment: Sorry maybe I misunderstood you. But the data are already stored I just need a smaller table or view to query to. Do you mean that using view is not going to improve performance and I have to switch to my initial idea to use a chron job and a normal table?

Comment: According to me yes. or you have to maintain the small table. and i am agree with the answer by "Used_By_Already" that a small table is always work fast.